# How to 3D plot Complex Fraction: Voltage Reflection Coefficient With Increasing Reactance

Tags: matlab, 3d

I am super struggling with this problem. I need to show in 3D how the magnitude of the Voltage Reflection Coefficient changes for a fixed Z_0 BUT with a changing Z_L, i.e. a changing load impedance.

It is not working at all and have no idea how to proceed. It seems MATLAB will not allow sum or difference operations for 3d plots.

```
clear,clc,cla,clf;

figure;

resistance = 0:10:400;
reactance = -400:10:400;

R = 50;     % Fixed resistance of Transmission Line
X = 0;      % Fixed reactance of Transmission Line

R_matrix = zeros(length(resistance),length(resistance));
R_matrix(:) = R;

X_matrix = zeros(length(reactance),length(reactance));
X_matrix(:) = X;


[RESISTANCE,REACTANCE] = meshgrid(resistance,reactance);


VRC = ((resistance - R_matrix).^2  + (reactance - X_matrix).^2) ./ ((resistance + R_matrix).^2 + (reactance - X_matrix).^2);

surf(RESISTANCE,REACTANCE,VRC);

xlabel('Resistance (\Omega)',"FontSize",14);
ylabel('Reactance X','FontSize',14);
zlabel('Voltage Reflection Coefficient','FontSize',14);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new answer to address the enquiries raised by the OP in comments:

```
resistance = linspace(0,99);
reactance = linspace(-100,100);
R = 50;     % Fixed resistance of Transmission Line
X = 0;      % Fixed reactance of Transmission Line

% 2D plot:
VRC = ((resistance - R).^2 + (reactance - X).^2) ./ ...
      ((resistance + R).^2 + (reactance + X).^2);
plot(resistance,VRC,reactance,VRC)
xlabel('Resistance (\Omega), Reactance X',"FontSize",12);
ylabel('Voltage Reflection Coefficient','FontSize',12);

% 3D plot:
[RESISTANCE,REACTANCE] = meshgrid(resistance,reactance);
VRC = ((RESISTANCE - R).^2 + (REACTANCE - X).^2) ./ ...
      ((RESISTANCE + R).^2 + (REACTANCE + X).^2);
figure
surf(RESISTANCE,REACTANCE,VRC);
xlabel('Resistance (\Omega)',"FontSize",12);
ylabel('Reactance X','FontSize',12);
zlabel('Voltage Reflection Coefficient','FontSize',12);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. I actually just figured it out during the night but yes, that's exactly where the error was - the mesh grid needed to be calculated before the plot - many thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

The resistance and reactance cannot have different lengths. Use `linspace(0,400)` and `linspace(-400,400)` to make sure both have 100 values, for example.

```
clear, clc, close

resistance = linspace(0,400);
reactance = linspace(-400,400);

R = 50;     % Fixed resistance of Transmission Line
X = 0;      % Fixed reactance of Transmission Line

R_matrix(1:length(resistance),1:length(resistance)) = R;
X_matrix(1:length(reactance),1:length(reactance)) = X;

VRC = ((resistance - R_matrix).^2 + (reactance - X_matrix).^2) ./ ...
      ((resistance + R_matrix).^2 + (reactance + X_matrix).^2);

[RESISTANCE,REACTANCE] = meshgrid(resistance,reactance);
surf(RESISTANCE,REACTANCE,VRC);

xlabel('Resistance (\Omega)',"FontSize",14);
ylabel('Reactance X','FontSize',14);
zlabel('Voltage Reflection Coefficient','FontSize',14);
```

[image]

**Edit:** The reflection coefficient can only approach zero if `ZL=Z0` because `Γ=(ZL−Z0)/(ZL+Z0)`. If you change `resistance = 0:100` you will get `Γ=0` at exactly `resistance=50`, because at `resistance=50` the `reactance` is zero.

Just change this line:

```
resistance = linspace(0,100);
```

to get the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you SOOOO MUCH for this! Really couldn't have done it without you! The only problem is, at 50 0hms, the VRC should be zero - it IS when plotted in 2D. For some reason, it reads much higher than zero and never falls to zero at all. If you could help with this I would be SO grateful.

Comment: Also, can I please have your name (/and institution) so I can acknowledge your help in my project? Many thanks!

Comment: If `ZL≠Z0` you cannot have the reflection coefficient approach zero because `Γ = (ZL−Z0) / (ZL+Z0)`. If you change `resistance = 0:100` you will get `Γ = 0` at exactly `resistance = 50`.

Comment: You can drop me an email at ssseif@nu.edu.sa if you want my name and institution.

Comment: Hi again, on looking into this further, I don't think your code works. The scale of the resistance, whether that be from 0-100 or 0-400 should not affect the magnitude of the voltage reflection coefficient as the transmission line impedance is already pre-defined at 50 Ohms. Does this make sense? The scale of the grid should therefore make no difference on the VRC. I think I am missing something fundamental in the code. The magnitude of the VRC should be zero at 50 Ohms regardless of the scale of the resistance. No?

Comment: Yes, and no. Let me explain. VRC should be zero if ZL=Z0, and since Z0=50 in your case, ZL should be 50 as well. This leads to resistance + reactance = 50, which means resistance = 50 and reactance = 0. So any range would be possible provided that it contains the (50+j0) point. I shifted the range in my code just to get that point (approximately).

Comment: Thank you! I still don't see why the range should make a difference if the functions are programmed correctly. The output implies that ZL=Z0 at the midpoint of the resistance range - which is obviously not correct. The other indication that this is wrong is that the VRC does not appear to change along the reactance scale - when plotted in 2D, i.e. when plotting the VRC as a function of a changing load reactance, the VRC does in fact change quite substantially. I would therefore expect the VRC to change in *both* directions in the output, both with resistance AND reactance. Do you agree?

Comment: @AdrianSalt - Please see my new answer fixing the independence of VRC on reactance. The error was in calculating VRC before building the `meshgrid` for both resistance and reactance.